# Problems to properly append chapter without numering to the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, etoolbox, titletoc

In my document I have a number of chapters, that have their numbering suppressed. I know that to append them to the table of contents one should use the `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and subsequently define

```
 \chapter*{Name of the chapter}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Name of the chapter}
```

This does the job and I get my chapters properly included. Unfortunately when using a Pdf viewer, I get a mismatch between the positions of the chapters and links in the table of contents. Clicking the name of the chapter, included via `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Name of the chapter}`, gets me to the wrong page. This is not the case for the normal chapters, but still is quite annoying.

Does anyone has ideas how this issue can be resolved?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don't need `etoolbox` for that, but you *do* need `\phantomsection` before `\chapter*`

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) you do not need etoolbox for this, (3) always post full minimal examples, (4) I'm guessing you are using hyperref, in that case you need `\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline `. The reason being that the hyper link need something to latch on to and `\chapter*` provides nothing

Comment: Thank you both. You solved my problem! The problem was the missing  `\phantomsection` and a potential conflict with `\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}` . I apologize for not providing a minimal example, next time I will know. Could you formulate your answers so that I can accept them.

Comment: @AlexanderCska: Unfortunately you can accept only one of the answers then ;-) And both haven't seen your comment probably because they weren't addressed properly: Use a `@` in front of the user-name to write an answer-comment to a user here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer added

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am still learning. One of the users already posted his answer. Anyway, thanks to both of them for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever `\addcontentsline` is used in conjunction with, say, `\chapter*` **and** the `hyperref` package is used, you need to use

```
\chapter*{...} 
\phantomsection 
\addcontentsline...
```

Because hyperlinks needs something to latch on to. Normally it would latch on to the changing chapter counter, but here no counter is used, so a phantom is needed.

Comment: Possibly `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection` before `\chapter*`, so the anchor will show the chapter title.